# How to use chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm a newbie to coding, and I wanted to know how to use chrome.storage.local to store variables.

This is my HTML and javascript code(its a very basic version of what I want)

```js
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': document.getElementById("userInput").value}, function() {
          // Notify that we saved.
          })
  
            chrome.storage.local.get(['value'], function(result) {
         OnTaskPage=result.key;
         document.getElementById("userInput").value = result;
        });
```

```html
<body>
<h1 id="userInput">What site do you want to stay on?</h1>
<input type="text" value="">
</body>
<script src="content.js"></script>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm messing up the javascript, but I don't know where because I am new to the syntax, and pretty much have no clue what I'm doing. The point of the javascript code is to store the value inside the html text box. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Move `id="userInput"` after `<input `

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- The `id` should be on `input` element, not on `h1`.
- `result` is an object so to access the value you need to read `result.value`, look for tutorials on using JavaScript objects.
- Currently you clear the saved value first by using set() with an empty value, and then read that empty value. You probably don't need set() here, but rather in some other event like a `click` on a button element.
- The script `content.js` is named ambiguously/incorrectly because content scripts are for web pages, not for the extension page, so it should be named differently, e.g. `popup.js`

```
chrome.storage.local.get({value: ''}, result => {
  OnTaskPage = result.value;
  document.getElementById('userInput').value = result.value;
});

document.getElementById('save').onclick = () => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({value: document.getElementById('userInput').value});
};
```

and html:

```html
<body>
  <h1>What site do you want to stay on?</h1>
  <input id="userInput">
  <button id="save">save</button>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```